# Evaluating test data set without label! - Is it possible evaluate?

Tags: machine-learning

In machine learning, We know that we should use the **test data** set when our model is ready to deploy. And before that, we train the model using **train data** set and split it into **train** and **validation** or cross-validation approach. Here, each set has the corresponding label.

So, evaluating or find the confusion matrix by predicting from the model is straightforward. We can first predict the `y_pred` and compare it to `y_val`. In this case, how to get the accuracy or measure the performance of the **test set** which has no label. And I know, it shouldn't have label set.

But, how to measure the performance for this **test set** or we just make sure the model performance only by using **train set**? Sound like a silly question but a quick suggestion or correction to me is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You have two options basically: label the test data (maybe just a portion) manually or trust the training accuracy and maybe lower it by 10%. I would advise the first approach.